# How to prevent git log --follow from following copies, but only follow renames?

Tags: git, logging, copy

If I'm copying a file without changing its content, `git log --follow` will always follow the copy source, no matter which `-Cxxx%` I'm specifying. How to prevent Git from following copies entirely, but still follow renames?

Example log for the entire repository shows `filec.txt` added in commit `53d9862f`:

```
$ git log --format=oneline --stat
e26820a3a80f1f85248cf0c5865a772546022324 modification 4
 filec.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
05ac468e19fbf382a0ff4aff1501d0d1b5217ea2 modification 3
 filec.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
a4cf5e076055399aa4a97bec61e1be7e972a905f other change
 other.txt | 3 +++
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
53d9862f8e244497c4d0dfd8b6ada9dce45b6e33 copy
 filec.txt | 5 +++++
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+)
ddd9b8d4cd8c22f9a673084c94eeec97c4d51542 modification 2
 file.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
af8be46361c349b261e649920d1b28efdcad542d modification 1
 file.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
c225a05105840dd348433cde65d4ba650a6cbb04 initial import
 file.txt | 3 +++
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
```

File log shows history past `53d9862f` where it should not do:

```
$ git log --format=oneline --follow filec.txt
e26820a3a80f1f85248cf0c5865a772546022324 modification 4
05ac468e19fbf382a0ff4aff1501d0d1b5217ea2 modification 3
53d9862f8e244497c4d0dfd8b6ada9dce45b6e33 copy
ddd9b8d4cd8c22f9a673084c94eeec97c4d51542 modification 2
af8be46361c349b261e649920d1b28efdcad542d modification 1
c225a05105840dd348433cde65d4ba650a6cbb04 initial import
```

Comment: ... don't set the "detect copy" option at all? (Note that this may require overriding `diff.renames = copy` if you have that configured; use `git -c diff.renames=true log ...` to do that.)  (This comment is corrected; I used `diff.rename` instead of `diff.renames` by mistake earlier.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. `git -c diff.renames=true log --format=oneline --follow filec.txt` still shows al commits. Even `-C diff.renames=false` has no effect.

Comment: Aha, `try_to_follow_renames` (in `tree-diff.c`, used any time `--follow` is in effect) forcibly sets `--find-copies-harder` internally. There is no way to turn this off. If the file is a copy, Git always switches to the copy. (This seems like a bug: you should be able to set or clear the copy-finding individually, even if it defaults to "set" for this case.)

Comment: Thanks, @torek. Sounds like your last comment is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is no direct way to defeat this, as it is hardcoded in the Git source (at least up through Git 2.13).

As a workaround, you can re-start the `git log --follow` from just before the commit in which Git has switched to another file.  In your example, after `git log --format=oneline --follow filec.txt` switches at commit `53d9862f8e244497c4d0dfd8b6ada9dce45b6e33`, you could run `git log --oneline --follow filec.txt 53d9862f8e244497c4d0dfd8b6ada9dce45b6e33^`, for instance.  This is kind of painful, and in my opinion there should be a way to make `git log --follow` not follow copies, but there isn't.